# sticky popping sounds coming from under my newly laid hardwood floors

Tags: floor, hardwood

i have a very annoying and frustrating problem.  there are sticky popping sounds coming from under my newly laid hardwood floors.  there is a underlay on cement base and the installer swears that he laid it as per specifications.  he is at a loss to know why the floor is doing that.  it started out in a couple of spots a few weeks after the floor was laid but it has moved to about 70% of the floor.  short of pulling the whole thing off ($15,000 down the gurgler) is there anything else that can be done? if i step on any area for longer than a few seconds then step off the floor snaps like 2 pieces sticking and then violently unsticking.

HELP i'm going insane. even my downstairs neighbors can hear the sticky pops late at night....

Comment: Is it solid hardwood, or engineered hardwood? What is the humidity like? was the floor nailed, stapled, or glued down? Did the installer leave a proper expansion gap around the perimeter of the floor?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Tester101  it is Solid hardwood, i'm in Melbourne Australia so the humidity is normal (no extreme high/low), it is glued down, and according to him, has allowed for the proper expansion gap etc...he told me he has 30 years experience. Nita Walker